# How can I convert a mp3 audio file to Opus audio file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, codec, opus

I declared the pathname of my mp3 audio file in my code as `var pathname: String = "/..../file.mp3"` (It's saved correctly, I can listen to it).
Can I convert that file to an Opus audio file? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that specific error, but the [Supported Media Formats page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) says Opus is only supported in Android 5.0+, and then only in the matroska container.

Make sure you're testing on newer Android, and you may need to demux manually to feed raw packets to the decoder.

If you need Opus support everywhere you can include the C library in your app and call it directly over JNI.

Comment: Oh, I don't get and error eheh, I don't knwo how to convert an mp3 to opus